# Read file line by line and delete after

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'd like to read `connectedclients.now` line by line, doing something while read each, and delete the line when done the work.

**Actually tried:**

*ClientWork.sh:*

```
unset n
while read -r user work codename; do
  echo $user $work $codename
  : $[n++]
done <connectedclients.now
sed "1 $n d" connectedclients.now
```

*Original code from [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180617/read-line-from-file-then-delete)*

Getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unexpected`,'` as an issue. Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Can you add part of your input file *and* your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arithmetic is wrong: `$[n++]`, instead try :

```
((n++))
```

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

and if you want to remove line by line :

```
n=0
while read -r user work codename; do
    echo "$user $work $codename"
    ((n++))
    sed -i "$n d" connectedclients.now
done < connectedclients.now
```

Comment: I get no more issue report, but the line does not echo when I run `bash ClientWork.sh`.

Comment: Because you ran a precedent execution, and the lines are deleted as intented/asked... just use `cat connectedclients.now`, lines should had diseapear

Comment: Where exactly to use `cat`?

Comment: Understand :) Alright, so the 'command' gets executed, but just isn't shown, correct?

Comment: `$[ ]` is just super old and slated for removal, but not "wrong" (in that it still works).

Comment: Deleting lines from the file whilst still processing it seems risky and inefficient. Why are you not simply dedeting the entire file when you're done? Or if you need to keep track of where you were when you got interrupted, write out the index to a separate temporary file.

Comment: I agree what triplee said

Comment: @gilles, inside the loop you always want to delete the first line, so you don't need the counter at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really need to remove lines as you're processing each line, I'd first read the whole file:

```
file=connectedclients.now
echo "before processing, $(wc -l < "$file") lines"

mapfile -t all_lines < "$file"
for line in "${all_lines[@]}"; do
    read -r user work codename <<<"$line"
    echo $user $work $codename
    sed -i 1d "$file"
done

echo "after processing, $(wc -l < "$file") lines"
```